# Indesign XSLT Select Random Image From Folder

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I'm using Indesign to import StatCrew XML files and create post-game graphics.  I should probably give more detail. StatCrew generates a different xml file. Below is the full file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11sGFbXlkTlEwmzBVE-yMZVBbYYPLEwLK/view?usp=sharing

Here is my current XSLT file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJ6ltaz-sxufFBV7QCsjFn7l36HxKeHJ/view?usp=sharing

Using the XSLT above, I can find the player that scored the most points and have indesign select a photo from a directory that is the same name as the @uni number. In this example, Indesign would display the .psd file named 05.psd.

Exported from Indesign as a JPG. I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j27cS.jpg

What I would like to do, however, is have Indesign select a .psd file at random from a FOLDER named 05. Is that possible? I'm learning all of this from information on the internet and have no real background in XML..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to find out which XSLT processor you can use with InDesign and if it supports some file system access and random number generation.

In XSLT 3 as supported by Saxon 9.8 and Altova 2017/2018 you can generate a random number https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-random-number-generator e.g.

```
random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?number
```

which will give a double between `0` (including) and `1` (excluded) you could then multiply by the number of images you have and round to get an integer number. Another option is to use the `permute` function of the random number generator with e.g.

```
random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?permute(1 to 20)[1]
```

to give you a random integer between `1` and `20` where of course you would adjust the expression `1 to 20` to the number of images you have.

It should also be possible with Saxon 9.8 to determine the `.psd` files in a location using e.g. `uri-collection('file:///C:/folder/subfolder?select=*.psd')` so you could then use

```
random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?permute(uri-collection('file:///C:/folder/subfolder?select=*.psd'))[1]
```

to directly select a random file URI from that location.

Comment: As a quick note, InDesign uses Xalan processor and only supports XSLT version 1.0

Comment: It requires an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 which depending on your project you might be able to plug in instead of Xalan.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with XSLT but an indesign script makes it easy. Here I add a url parameter that you can work with XSLT.

```js
var main = function() {
 var m = $.os[0]=="M",
 wf = "XML files : *.xml;",
 mf = function(f){return (f instanceof Folder) || /\.xml$/.test(f.name)},
 f = File.openDialog( "Please select xml file…", m? mf : wf ),
 xo,
 ps, p, n,
 uni,
 baseFolder = Folder ( Folder.desktop ),
 playerFolder, psds, fileAttr;
 
 if ( !f ) return;
 
 f.open('r');
 f.encoding = "UTF-8";
 xo = XML( f.read() );
 f.close();
 
 ps = xo.player;
 n = ps.length();
 
 while ( n-- ) {
  p = ps[n];
  
  uni = String(p.@uni);
  playerFolder = Folder ( baseFolder+"/"+uni );
  if ( !playerFolder.exists ) {
   fileAttr = uni+".psd";
  }
  else {
   psds = playerFolder.getFiles ( "*.psd" );
   if ( !psds.length ) {
    fileAttr = uni+".psd"; 
   }
   else {
    fileAttr = uni+"/"+decodeURI(psds[ getRandomInt ( 0, psds.length )].name);
   }
  }
  p.@url = fileAttr;
 }
 
 f.open( 'w');
 f.write ( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r'+xo.toXMLString() );
 f.close();
 
 f.execute();
 
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var u;

app.doScript ( "main()",u,u,UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "The Script" );
```

Once run, it will prompt you for a XML file and will add a new attribute (url) that contains the random url.

```js
<player url="05/A.psd" uni="05" code="05" name="ONE, Player" checkname="ONE,PLAYER" class="JR" gp="1">
```

Then you can tweak your xsl:

```js
           <xsl:copy-of select="$WBB_player_location" />player/<xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
```

Comment: I know nothing about scripts...but I'll play with this later today and see what comes from it